# Dynamically expand ALL lists and records from json

Tags: powerquery, m

I want to expand all lists and records in a json response.
Columns are like e.g. (this is dynamically, it also can be 10 records and 5 lists):

Text, Text, [List], [List], Text, [Record], [Record], String, [Record]

I wrote a function for getting all columns with the specific type

```
Cn.GetAllColumnsWithType = (table as table, typ as type) as list =>
let
    ColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(table),
    ColumnsOfType = List.Select(ColumnNames, (name) =>
        List.AllTrue(List.Transform(Table.Column(table, name), (cell) => Type.Is(Value.Type(cell), typ))))
in
    ColumnsOfType;
```

and a function to expand all lists from a table

```
Cn.ExpandAllListsFromTable = (table as table, columns as list) =>
let
    expandedListTable = List.Accumulate(columns, table, (state, columnToExpand) =>
        Table.ExpandListColumn(state, columnToExpand))
in
    expandedListTable;
```

all lists are now records and i want to dynamically expand all these records.

I think i need a foreach to iterate through the list (which are only records cause of Cn.GetAllColumnsWithType),
Table.ExpandRecordColumn each element with it's Table.ColumnNames and add it to the table but i don't know how to do it.
Maybe you can help me out cause it's driving me crazy.
Cheers

Edit:
I recently opened a thread but there i wanted to expand a specific one like

```
#"SelectItems" = Table.SelectColumns(records,{"$items"}),
#"$items1" = #"SelectItems"{0}[#"$items"],
```

but now i want to do it all dynamically.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output of what you want?

Answer (score 6):

Chris Webb wrote a function to do this for Table-type columns:

http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/

I've shared a tweaked version of that that I made for Record-type columns:

https://gist.github.com/Mike-Honey/0a252edf66c3c486b69b

Comment: thanks, that worked like a charm in power bi query editor. For the test I added a function for that and named it "ExpandAllRecords". But i have a problem with adding that function to the Power BI Connector in M. I'm a little bit confused because you create a M file for that and didn't name the function itself. I tried it with 
'Cn.ExpandAllRecords = (TableToExpand as table, optional ColumnNumber as number) => let Source = (TableToExpand as table, optional ColumnNumber as number) = > let ...'

Comment: This all predates the Power BI Connector. Instead, create a new Blank Query, open the Advanced Editor and paste in that code.  Name the query ExpandAllRecords.  Then in your main query, you can call that function in an Add Custom Column step or in M code, passing your record-type column.

Comment: In general i develop a PowerBI Connector with M code in Visual Studio. I don't know exactly how to use your github code cause ExpandAllRecords is called recursive and i don't know where and how to declare the ExpandAllRecords function right. I created the function like i wrote in the comment above but that didn't work. A little bit hard to explan but i hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Sorry I haven't coded with the Power BI Connector before.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a function for that. Assuming that the previous step in M was named `Removed Other Columns`, and that the column to expand is named `Data`, then make regular Expand step and replace its code of `#"Expanded Data"` with the following code:

```
#"Expanded Data"
  = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    #"Removed Other Columns", 
    "Data", 
    List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Other Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_)))
  )
```

It expands all columns without referencing their names.

Comment: When I tried this I got an error for List columns: `Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Table.`

Comment: @iX3 Make careful check that you do everything as should be. 1. Before expanding columns add step `Remove other columns`. 2 You should have column named Data which contains tables. 3 Expand column Data traditional way by clicking the icon of two arrows pointing in opposite directions which is in the column header. 4. Replace autogenerated code of the `Expanded Data` step with the code in my answer.

Comment: This step is returning the error for me: List.Transform(#"Removed Other Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_)).  I wasn't able to resolve it so I used the function above.

Comment: Make sure you rename the previous step to "Removed Other Columns". And the column to expand is named "Data". If instead of renaming previous step setup you try to adjust the code, be aware that previous step name and "Data" column name are in multiple places in the code. BTW it might be helpful to mention the error message.