# Automatically Expand all "Table Columns" with specific name

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm a beginner in coding and am not familiar with "M" modeling language. I have an XML file that I want to use to load the data in Query Editor. In the Query, I need to expand only the table columns with a specific name below:

1. view
2. viewfolder
3. Attribute:name

I have found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542013/dynamically-expand-all-lists-and-records-from-json) where they give a [function by Chris Webb](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/) for expanding all the lists(below code).

```
= (TableToExpand as table, optional ColumnNumber as number) =>
    let
     ActualColumnNumber = if (ColumnNumber=null) then 0 else ColumnNumber,
     ColumnName = Table.ColumnNames(TableToExpand){ActualColumnNumber},
     ColumnContents = Table.Column(TableToExpand, ColumnName),
     ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(ColumnContents, each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
     NewColumnNames = List.Transform(ColumnsToExpand, each ColumnName & "." & _),
     CanExpandCurrentColumn = List.Count(ColumnsToExpand)>0,
     ExpandedTable = if CanExpandCurrentColumn then Table.ExpandTableColumn(TableToExpand, ColumnName, ColumnsToExpand, NewColumnNames) else TableToExpand,
     NextColumnNumber = if CanExpandCurrentColumn then ActualColumnNumber else ActualColumnNumber+1,
     OutputTable = if NextColumnNumber>(Table.ColumnCount(ExpandedTable)-1) then ExpandedTable else ExpandAll(ExpandedTable, NextColumnNumber)
    in
     OutputTable
```

But how to expand only desired lists/tables?

[image: Query Editor Screenshot update]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply put a filter on the old `ColumnsToExpand` line.

That is,

```
 TableColumns = //This is the old ColumnsToExpand definition renamed.
     List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(ColumnContents, each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
 ColumnsToExpand =
     List.Select(TableColumns, each (_ = "view" or _ = "viewfolder" or _ = "Attribute:name")),
```

Or in one line like this,

```
 ColumsToExpand = List.Select(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(ColumnContents, each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))), each (_ = "view" or _ = "viewfolder" or _ = "Attribute:name")),
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, Thank you. I would also like to rename the column headers respectively. For the first viewfolder found the name should be viewfolder1 and for the second it's viewfolder 2, and for the Attribute:name found after viewfolder 2, the column name should be view 2. Is this possible?                           I have updated the screenshot and the files above respectively.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, so I'd suggest posting it separately.

Comment: Sure, Thanks again

Comment: I have created another question related to this code. Can you please check it out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222986/power-query-recursive-function-add-more-steps-after-the-recursive-step